# How can I make divs bunch up vertically?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I make all divs with different heights bunch together vertically whilst having them in columns? Each of the divs in my website float left with a 5px margin on the right and bottom so that two columns are made but with them all different heights the bottom margins are different depending on the tallest div in that row, how can I make them bunch up like on this [Google Now](https://www.google.com/landing/now/#cards) page?

I have made a basic version of my website in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthewbowker/p1k462qb/).

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="tile" class="tile-1"></div>
    <div id="tile" class="tile-2"></div>
    <div id="tile" class="tile-3"></div>
    <div id="tile" class="tile-4"></div>
    <div id="tile" class="tile-5"></div>
    <div id="tile" class="tile-6"></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 210px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

#tile {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    background-color: #333;
    float: left;
}

.tile-1 { height: 100px; }
.tile-2 { height: 130px; }
.tile-3 { height: 80px; }
.tile-4 { height: 100px; }
.tile-5 { height: 110px; }
.tile-6 { height: 150px; }
```

I have done it previously by making each column have their own container but when the browser window shrinks I need the 'tiles' to merge but keep their order, going from reading the page like a book to reading it like a list for smaller screens.

Thanks in advance.
Matt

Comment: Need to use Masonary for that, you cannot do that by CSS only

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these

- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) (probably most popular)
- [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [jQuery.waterfall](http://dfcreative.github.io/projects/waterfall/)
- [Wookmark jQuery plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)

See examples and you will achieve this easily.